# Create this string exactly in Android

Tags: android, asp.net, format, http-post, name-value

I want to build 2 same products for Android and iOs.
The iOs already works, but the android doesnt, that's because of the format of the string.

in iOs this is:

```
NSString*jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"{\"id\":\"%@\",\"longitude\":\"%@\",\"latitude\":\"%@\",\"timestamp\":\"%@\"}", _phonenumber, longitude , latitude, stringFromDate];
```

And i dont know how to do this exactely like this in android. The format here is different.
What i have now is:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.myserver.nl/locatie.php");

```
try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", num));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", longi));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", lat));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timestamp", time));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

Thanks in advance, i need this by the end of the week so if you could help me, that would be greatly appreciated

i get this as an result from the iOs string:

```
{
    "id":"0612833398",
    "longitude":"-143.406417",
    "latitude":"32.785834",
    "timestamp":"10-10 07:56"
}
```

**Okay, this is what my problem is.**

Yes i need to send this exact string to an asp.net file on a server. But i need to know how to combine this with this: with the http post to

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.myserver.nl/locatie.php");
```

before i combined this with the nameValuePPairs like this

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Comment: JSONObject is your friend for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create same string as you are getting in IOS by create an JosnObject as:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
json.put("id", "0612833398"); 
json.put("longitude", "-143.406417"); 
json.put("latitude", "32.785834"); 
json.put("timestamp", "10-10 07:56");
```

now if you make a print for json object you will get this string :

```
{"id":"0612833398","longitude":"-143.406417","latitude":"32.785834",
                                                   "timestamp":"10-10 07:56"}
```

and Post JSONObject as to server :

```
  try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.myserver.nl/locatie.php");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

// Create json object here...
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
    json.put("id", "0612833398"); 
    json.put("longitude", "-143.406417"); 
    json.put("latitude", "32.785834"); 
    json.put("timestamp", "10-10 07:56"); 

/// create StringEntity with current json obejct

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString()); 
    se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
    httppost.setEntity(se); 

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

  }
```

Comment: i edited my question so you'll understand what the problem now is

Comment: You need to run the whole code above in a separate thread for it to work.

Comment: the whole code means 2 times the same, because i am getting all errors when i only add the Post JSONOBJECT as to server part of your post

Comment: @Babboe : friend i mean just use my code to post json string to server and remove or comment your on httpclient code

Comment: @Babboe : if you are facing any issue in integrating my code with current code then just give me pastebin link to me i will edit for you.Thanks

Comment: @Babboe : put your relevant class code [here](http://pastebin.com/) and give me link

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22118/discussion-between-babboe-and--k)

Comment: Hmm there seems to be a problem
it doesnt send the jsonstring with the url
When i look in my php, it only sends the url

Comment: @Babboe : how you are receiving it in php side?

Comment: POST: 
Array
(
)



 GET: 
Array
(
    [data] => 
)

Comment: When i use this code in php: file_put_contents('dump.txt', "POST: \n" . print_r($_POST, true) . "\n\n\n GET: \n" . print_r($_GET, true));

Answer (score 2):

To create a String you can use String.format(). In this case the syntax is very similar to Objective-C:

```
String s = String.format("{\"id\":\"%s\",\"longitude\":\"%s\",\"latitude\":\"%s\",\"timestamp\":\"%s\"}", num, long, lat, time);
```

HTTP Post goes like this:

```
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);


try {

HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

params.setParameter(name, value);


postMethod.setParams(params);

httpClient.execute(postMethod);


} catch (Exception e) {

} finally {

postMethod.abort();

}
```

Comment: Okay, but how do i use this than in correct format for Android. I cant use the nameValuePairs rigth now

Comment: This gives you a String like your NSString in iOS. I don't know what you want to do with it exactly so i don't know what correct format you want.

Comment: i edited my question so you'll understand what the problem now is