# Delete brackets around BasicNameValuePair

Tags: android, json

When i log my namevaluepair i get this in my console.

```
01-07 13:51:55.137: I/System.out(723): URL:[data={"id":"69403","timestamp":"07-01-2013 13:51:55","longitude":"-122.084095","latitude":"37.422005"}]
```

But i need to delete the [ and ]. Does anybody know how to do this?

Here's the android code that does this.

```
json = new JSONObject(); 
        try { 

            json.put("longitude", longi); 

            json.put("latitude", lat); 
            json.put("timestamp", time); 

            json.put("id", "69403"); 


        } catch (JSONException e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

        /// create StringEntity with current json obejct 

        try { 
      //  StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString()); 

            List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", json.toString()));
            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
            System.out.println("URL:" + httpost);
            System.out.println("URL:" + nvps);


            System.out.println("send about to do post");
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
                System.out.println("URL:" + httpost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: but why do you want to delete?

Comment: @ChintanRathod -- he want to get values from json object

Comment: Because i already built a working copy for an iOs application that sends the exact same string. It is almost an exact duplicate, only thing is that the brackets are around the string

Comment: use substring - something like this:json.toString().substring( 1, json.toString().length()-2 )

Comment: Im sorry, i dont know how to. Could you type it as an answer and in the way that i can immediately implement it in my code. Than i can also accept it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

post your jsonObject  without using `BasicNameValuePair` as:

```
 StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString()); 
 se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
 httppost.setEntity(se);
```

Comment: @Babboe : see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027066/how-to-send-a-json-object-over-request-with-android) post .this code is tested by me

Comment: Isnt there an easier way to just delete the brackets around the httppost?

Comment: @Babboe : but i think i already answered same issue in your last question see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138722/create-this-string-exactly-in-android/14138904#14138904) because this is right way to post json to server you have any issue in this code ?

Comment: No i thaught this was the right way to do it. i know i am almost there. The only thing is the brackets around the "nvps" is making it inpossible. Dont you know how to delete them?

Comment: Do you know how to it, because if i try to implement your code i only get errors/crashes.. Or i am implementing it wrong

Comment: @Babboe : plz edit your post with latest code and crashes logs then i will try to help u more

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22324/discussion-between-babboe-and--k)

Comment: I put it all in the discussion

Comment: Didnt saw anything unusual?

Answer (score 0):

work around code:

use substring like this to your output

your ouput

```
URL:[data={"id":"69403","timestamp":"07-01-2013 13:51:55","longitude":"-122.084095","latitude":"37.422005"}]
```

do like this, the starting 6 words ll get deleted or removed

```
String op = yourOutputString.substring(6)
```